# Big Sur bluetooth keyboard not found after changing batteries. Mac mini

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth, big-sur

My keyboard battery's got to 5% so I changed to new ones. Keyboard was not discovered by mac so I restarted the machine. I now have the login asking for a password and the bluetooth setup assistant telling me the keyboard is not connected and to make it discoverable.
I have tested the keyboard on another mac mini ru ning high Sierra and it works fine.

I can't enter a password to get the big sur mac mini started - any suggestions on how to proceed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your Bluetooth keyboard has a charging cable (Magic Keyboard 2), connect that between your Mac and the keyboard to pair them.

If not, turn off the keyboard holding the power button, then turn it back on and continue holding the power button after it turns on, until the green LED is flashing. This puts the keyboard into pairing mode and makes it discoverable for your Mac mini's Bluetooth setup assistant.